# Добавление метки по адресу здания

Tags: java, android

Как добавить метку на здание при вводе его адреса?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс `Geocoder` для преобразования ширины и долготы из адреса.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);  
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

После того как получите координаты, с помощью `Marker` и `MarkerOptions` добавляйте метку.